# Validation in react antd doesnt changes on select change

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want the * icon and validation message to move on select change. Currently but only * sign changes but the validation message stays there till i click on submit button

[image]

First the account type is resedential so first name and last name is required.
But as soon as i change the account type from resedential to commercial company name should be required.

[image]

As you see in the image the * sign chages but validation doesnt shifts.
Can any one help me with this. I am using antd. Here is my Code snippet!

here is my code

```js
{({ getFieldValue }) => (
  <>
    <Col span={24} xl={8} lg={8} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>
      <Form.Item
        rules={[
          {
            required:
              getFieldValue("account_type") === "Residential"
                ? true
                : false,
            validateTrigger: "onChange",
          },
        ]}
        name={"first_name"}
        label="first name"
        className="mb-3"
      >
        <Input
          onChange={(e) => handleStringOnly(e, "first_name")}
          onBlur={handleDuplicateCustomersFirstNameValue}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Col>
    <Col span={24} xl={8} lg={8} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>
      <Form.Item
        name={"last_name"}
        rules={[
          {
            required:
              getFieldValue("account_type") === "Residential"
                ? true
                : false,
          },
        ]}
        label="last name"
        className="mb-3"
      >
        <Input
          onChange={(e) => handleStringOnly(e, "last_name")}
          onBlur={handleDuplicateCustomersLastNameValue}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Col>
    <Col span={24} xl={8} lg={8} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>
      <Form.Item
        rules={[
          {
            required:
              getFieldValue("account_type") === "Commercial"
                ? true
                : false,
          },
        ]}
        className="mb-3"
        name={"company_name"}
        label="Company Name"
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Col>
  </>
)}
```

Comment: You can validate fields when you change account type. In Account Type Select, use onChange function and validate fields like this `onChange={async () => await validateFields(['first_name', 'last_name', 'company_name'])}`.

Comment: is validateFields a function. and if yes than what to call in that?

Comment: validateFields is a function. Just like you get `getFieldValue` function, you can also get validateFields function. In my previous comment, you need to pass an array of namePath fields you want to validate.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of that function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validateFields` method to validate any field. If no value is passed to validate method, it will validate all the form values. But in your case you want revalidate `first_name`, `last_name` and `company_name` if you change `account_type`.

```
import { Col, Form, Input, Select } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';

const { Item } = Form;

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Form>
            <Item shouldUpdate noStyle>
                {/* Here get validateFields method */}
                {({ getFieldValue, validateFields }) => (
                    <>
                        <Col span={24} xl={8} lg={8} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>
                            <Item
                                rules={[{ required: getFieldValue('account_type') === 'Residential', validateTrigger: 'onChange' }]}
                                name={'first_name'}
                                label='first name'
                                className='mb-3'
                            >
                                <Input />
                            </Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={24} xl={8} lg={8} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>
                            <Item
                                name={'last_name'}
                                rules={[{ required: getFieldValue('account_type') === 'Residential' }]}
                                label='last name'
                                className='mb-3'
                            >
                                <Input />
                            </Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={24} xl={8} lg={8} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>
                            <Item
                                rules={[{ required: getFieldValue('account_type') === 'Commercial' }]}
                                className='mb-3'
                                name={'company_name'}
                                label='Company Name'
                            >
                                <Input />
                            </Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={24} xl={8} lg={8} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>
                            <Item name='account_type' label='Account Type'>
                                <Select
                                    options={[
                                        { label: 'Residential', value: 'Residential' },
                                        { label: 'Commercial', value: 'Commercial' }
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={async () => {
                                        // Now pass an array of all the fields you want to validate
                                        // For example, if you want to validate first_name, last_name and company_name
                                        await validateFields(['first_name', 'last_name', 'company_name']);
                                    }}
                                />
                            </Item>
                        </Col>
                    </>
                )}
            </Item>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-trigger validation using FormInstance.
this is the signature of validateFields `(nameList?: NamePath[]) => Promise`

you initialise form variable like this   `const [form]: any = Form.useForm();`
and use it like so `form.validateFields(['DaysNumber1','DaysNumber2'])`

```
export const Filters = ({}: Props) => {
  const [form]: any = Form.useForm();

  /* track field value change */
  const DaysNumber2_watch = Form.useWatch("DaysNumber2", form);

  useEffect(() => {
    /* when days2 change re-do validation */
    form.validateFields(["DaysNumber1"]);
  }, [DaysNumber2_watch]);

  return (
    <Form form={form} name="filters">
      <Form.Item name="DaysNumber1" label="Days-1" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="DaysNumber2" label="Days-2" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```